# Как можно реализовать такой переход?

Tags: html, css

[image: Как можно реализовать такую полоску??]

Как можно реализовать такой переход?

Comment: псевдоэлементом, фоном, svg, что душа пожелает

Comment: Какой переход??

Comment: @Baryonyx, выделен пунктирной линией на картинке

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> смотреть на полном экране

```css
:root{
  --width:calc(100vw - 16px);
}

*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
header{
  width:var(--width);
  height:100vh;
  background:url(https://images.pond5.com/defocused-abstract-background-night-city-footage-011498478_prevstill.jpeg);
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
main{
  width:var(--width);
  background:#fff;
  position: relative;
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
main:after{
  content:"";
  border-left:0px solid transparent;
  border-right:var(--width) solid #fff;
  border-top:15vh solid transparent;
  border-bottom:10px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top:-15vh; left:0; right:0;
}
.forma{
  width:250px;
  transform:translate(0,-200px);
  text-align:center;
  padding:20px;
  background:#fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index:100;
  border:1px solid #ccc;

}
.forma h2{
   font-family:Helvetica;
  font-weight:900;
  font-size:1.3em;
}
input{
  display:block;
  padding:4px;
  outline:none;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  color:#ccc;
  width:80%;
  margin:10px auto;
}
.forma p{
  font-size:12px;
  text-align:left;
  width:80%;
  margin:15px auto;
}
.text{
  width:300px;
  padding:20px;
  
}
.text h2{
  text-transform:uppercase;
  padding:10px 4px;
}
.text p{
  font-size:14px;
}
ul{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  list-style:none;
  padding-right:20px;
}
ul li{
  margin-right:20px;
}
ul a{
  color:#fbfbfb;
  font-size:1.2em;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.header-wrapper{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items:center;
  padding:20px 0;
  
}
header img{
  width:180px;
  height:30px;
  margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.pngmart.com/files/4/Microsoft-Logo-Transparent-PNG.png" alt="">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">item1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <div class="text">
    <h2>welcome User</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In, accusamus sint doloribus voluptatem mollitia esse amet dignissimos quis voluptas a vitae, quia, minus voluptatibus nemo tempore quae repellat omnis laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="forma">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit </h2>
    <form action="">
      <input type="text" placeholder="name">
      <input type="text" placeholder="nickname">
      <input type="email" placeholder="email">
      <input type="password" placeholder="password">
      <button>letter my now</button>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique exercitationem id impedit nobis sequi eaque recusandae?</p>
    </form>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.box1 {
  height: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
}

.box2 {
  height: 250px;
  background: tomato;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box2:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 75px 500px;
  border-color: transparent transparent tomato #222;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: В данном случае будет без адаптивности

Answer (score 3):

Адаптивное решение с помощью градиентов и тригонометрии

```js
// Переводит радианы в углы
Math.degrees = function(radians) {
  return radians * 180 / Math.PI;
};
function transitionEffect()
{
//Вынести размеры блока в переменную
var h = $(".transition").height(), w = $(".transition").width();
//Узнать гипотенузу
var hypotenuse = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(h,2) + Math.pow(w,2));
//Узнать угол
var angle = Math.acos((Math.pow(w,2) + Math.pow(hypotenuse,2) - Math.pow(h,2)) / (2*w*hypotenuse));
//Добавить градиент для блока .transition
$(".transition").css("background", `linear-gradient(-${Math.degrees(angle)}deg, #aaa 50%, #333 50.2%)`);
}
  transitionEffect();

$(window).resize(function(){
  transitionEffect();
});
```

```css
body {
margin:0;
}

.transition {
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
}
.block-black {
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background:#333;
}
.block {
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background:#aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="block-black"></div>
<div class="transition"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```